# Graphical differences between Photoshop and Paint Tool Sai

Tags: adobe-photoshop, line-art, drawing-tablet, sai

Me and my friend were discussing about Paint Tool Sai and Photoshop.
About the lining systems.

He claims that when you make a line using a drawing tablet, Paint Tool Sai calculates the path and draws it smoother by filling in the bumps.

The bumps are what I get when I draw a straight line in Photoshop. In photoshop for some reason, I get bumpy lines.

What are the differences? Why is Photoshop giving me bumpy lines if I draw as fast and the same as in Sai?

My drawing tablet is UGEE and his is Huion if that's any difference too.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

SAI has a line smoothing algorithm that samples many points and averages the path. The downside of this is that the feedback gets slower. Given that Photoshop does not have a stellar feedback speed to begin with it may not feel like that. Quite many applications are way better at painting and sketching digitally than Phostohop (Including SAI, Sketchbook, Krita and so on).

I did a quick search and found at least one app that brings in the kind of lazy eval smoothing for Photoshop [here](http://lazynezumi.com/), or any other app you might want to use it in.