# What is good Vector Software with a pencil tool?

Tags: vector, software-recommendation, sai

I am struggling to find a vector program that is set up similar to Paint Tool SAI or mainly used for sketching. It seems like all the ones I have tried don't even have just a plain pencil tool. Maybe I'm just missing something? The artists I like never seem to tell whether they're  programs are Vector or not. Help?

Comment: related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71061/graphical-differences-between-photoshop-and-paint-tool-sai

Answer (score 4):

Vector graphics is used differently than painting/drawing. You do not usually "draw" or sketch anything in a vector graphics software, your constructing a solution. Much like cutting paper for use as a mask. Most vector software do have a brush and pen tool, its just that it is entirely useless in terms of what your usually doing so you do not see people using it much.

Fine art is seldom vector graphics, mainly because vector graphics are a design tool first. The benefits of having a design that can be later altered is pretty big in terms of productivity. This kind of thing hardly ever touches fine art, the artist is there in the center of things. But then the artist wouldn't be doing 1,000 pages worth of rehash of the same concept in a few weeks.

Also read:

- [Why are raster images still used when vector images have so many advantages?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/44855/why-are-raster-images-still-used-when-vector-images-have-so-many-advantages/44857#44857)
- [How are these swirly, line frames made?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71816/how-are-these-swirly-line-frames-made/71820#71820), to understand the construction.
- [How do I split a circle shape into diaphragm-like segments in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53169/how-do-i-split-a-circle-shape-into-diaphragm-like-segments-in-illustrator/53179#53179), another on construction.

**TL;DR;**

An art analogy would be that: Vector graphics has more in common with paper cutouts than drawing or painting.